# in ASP.NET MVC3 Razor @Html.Raw(Json.Encode does not compute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I just upgraded an ASP.NET MVC app to version 3.0 and Razor.

I have the following code in my home page:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        /*@cc_on@*/
        var LastUserSetting = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["LastUserSetting"] == "" ? "''" : ViewData["LastUserSetting"]));
    </script>
```

In the browser, this ends up showing as:

```
var LastUserSetting = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["LastUserSetting"] == "" ? "''" : ViewData["LastUserSetting"]));
```

With the following error message: "reference to undefined XML name @Html"

which is obviously not what I intended.

What Am I missing? What did I do wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: why are you passing something to your view that isn't fully resolved anyway?

Comment: What is the location, name and extension of the view file? Where does that error occur?

Comment: @nathangonzalez What do you mean?  I am just trying to pass in a value for a variable. Thats all. And razor fails at resolving '@Html'

Comment: @AndrewBarber This is in my master page.  In Views/Shared/.  It is called Simple.Master.  There is no error on the server.  The error message is in Firefox and when I view the page I see that ASP.NET pushed the string as it to the browser without resolving it.

Comment: That's your problem. See my answer.

Comment: @user277498, generally what you pass to your view should not need to be mucked with.  json encode it in the controller, put it in an MvcString property in your viewmodel, and then use that variable directly in your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Razor code inside a WebForms master page. That does not work. Razor syntax only works in Razor views (cshtml or vbhtml)

So you need to switch back to using the WebForms syntax in that master, or switch to using actual Razor views.

Comment: Thanks! It appears that I need to change my pages to their razor equivalent one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your razor code withing single quotes:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    /*@cc_on@*/
    var LastUserSetting = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["LastUserSetting"] == "" ? "''" : ViewData["LastUserSetting"]))';
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I already have single and double quotes in the string, enclosing it in another set of single quotes breaks the line and causes errors